# BNF/EBNF/other grammar specification format repositories

Tags: grammar, dsl, bnf, ebnf

I'm developing a python library for domain specific languages and I want to include as many language definitions as possible. For regular expressions it's easy, since the format is the same across all implementation and there are several repositories out there like regexlib.

Is there any online library/repository available with loads of BNF/eBNF language examples (like regexlib.com)?

Answer (score 2):

The [Grammar Zoo](http://slps.github.io/zoo/index.html) from the [Software Language Processing Suite project](http://slps.github.io/) might help you.